# Can there be sheep in a biome with wolves around?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I spawned in an area where it seems there's mostly wolves.

I was wondering if I had to get rid of all of them in order to be able to get sheep.

I'm in a snowy/hilly area. I was thinking that there might be more sheep in the nearby wood biome but not luck. Further north, I have a mountain/grass area but only pigs there.

Comment: I don't think it's related, sometimes wolves will go after sheep and kill them, so they can spawn near eachother. You could have a look at: http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Spawn

Comment: I don't think sheep spawn on snow? Well lit grass should attract sheep.

Comment: I need to have sheep already in an area. Following this condition, then if I kill all the sheeps, they will respawn in the same area.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the wiki:

- [Sheep](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Sheep) can spawn on Grass blocks with a 2x2x1 (minimum) space above them. As a passive mob, they also require light to spawn.
- [Wolves](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Wolf) can spawn in Grass, in Forest and Taiga biomes.

It doesn't seem like there's anything to stop wolves and sheep spawning in the same area. However, the wiki also says:

- [Mobs](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Mobs) will frequently spawn in groups with mobs of the same variety.
- Randomness for animal [spawning](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spawn) is derived from the world seed, which means that worlds with the same seed will generate chunks with the same animals in the same places.
- Very rarely, new animals can [spawn](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spawn) in already generated chunks, just like monsters do

So it seems unlikely that killing the wolves will have any effect on whether you get sheep. If you want to get wool you'll probably have to go exploring, but if you're lucky you might get sheep spawning in an area you've already explored.